# Latex does not split the Word to pass next line

Tags: hyphenation

Normally, the word (e.g. 'thermal' in the image) should be splited at the end of line and should go to next line. However the word continues till out of the margins. 
How can i prevent this ?

[image]

Comment: Could you add an MWE or just examples of your preamble? This could be a case of penalties set too strictly or incorrectly, potentially.

Comment: Yes please add a MWE http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that. If everything else is okay, an option coud be `\hyphenation{ther-mal}`(define splitting option)

Comment: The American English hyphenation patterns allow `ther-mal`; to the contrary, the British English patterns give `thermal` (no possible hyphenation). It looks like you have `\usepackage[british]{babel}`

Comment: This seems a precise choice, because “normal” and “formal” share the same fate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

while knowing how the hyphenation you're (not) seeing is determined requires
knowing what patterns you're using, you can override them by putting an
exception into your preamble.  in this case,

```
\hyphenation{ther-mal}
```

(as suggested in a comment) would be the appropriate action.

i hava a copy of the oxford minidictionary (allegedly) used to develop the
uk patterns, and this is what it contains:

- formal (and informal) are not broken at all;
- nor:mal allowed to break at the : under extreme circumstances (e.g. narrow measure);
- ther|mal may be hyphenated without restriction at the | .

the uk patterns contain an entry that always suppresses hyphenation before
"mal", which i find confusing given the evidence.